# Google Chrome is stuck connecting when I'm trying to launch localhost on port 5500

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, localhost

I am trying to launch my javascript program on localhost with VSCcode. In VSCode the server is started on 5500. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM6de.jpg)

But when I try to launch it by writing localhost:5500, the server gets stuck on connecting. I don't know why but I'm frustrated because I usually google for the problem, but this time I need help. I have tried everything from re-installing Chrome to updating it but nothing is working. please help

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Probably port 5500 is user by other service. Try changing your port.
I think, you are trying to run a local server for a web application in react, node, flask or django, may be something else.